# Подскажите алгоритм разбиения строки на подстроки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, алгоритм, строки, текст

Дано: строка S, число N.
Нужно разбить строку на подстроки так, чтобы

1. Разбиение происходило в местах пробелов(сам пробел удаляется)
2. Длина каждой подстроки не превышала N символов за исключением случая, когда 1 слово больше N символов, тогда оно не разбивается.

Пример: S="Один два три большоеидлинное". N=6
Выход: "Один", "два", "три","большоеидлинное".

Данный алгоритм нужен мне, чтобы разместить длинную строку в ограниченной графе таблицы.

Видимо, это нужно сделать с помощью регулярных выражений, но я не могу подобрать правильного.

Comment: а вот при таких исходных данных S="Один два три большоеидлинное". N=10, выход должен  быть такой: "Один два", "три","большоеидлинное"?

Comment: regex не позволяет делать фильтр на N>6, regex позволяет побить текст на фрагменты по 6 символов например.

Comment: @KoVadim Да, именно так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Алгоритм подобной разбивки такой.

```
начало = 0
лимит = 6
разделитель = 0
пока начало < длина строки:
  разделитель = найти разделитель от позиции начало+лимит "с конца" строки
  если начало == разделитель:
    это длинная подстрока
    разделитель = найти разделитель от позиции начало+лимит к концу строки
  добавить подстроку [начало, разделитель) в список
  начало = разделитель + 1
```

код написан на питоноподобном алгоритмическом языке, так как в исходном вопросе язык не указан.

Answer (score 2):

Данное решение возможно только в языках с поддержкой условного просмотра назад ( PHP, Python, да и всё, что нормально поддерживает PCRE).
Задача решается не разбиением (`split`), а поиском совпадений (`match_all`). Разбиением ее можно решить только в языках с поддержкой условного просмотра назад неограниченной длины (С#, .NET), и то возможно, что это нельзя будет корректно реализовать.

Экспериментировать можно здесь:
https://regex101.com/r/Rvvwfz/2

Регулярное выражение:

```
(?<=\s|^)(\S{11,}|\S.{0,9})(?<!\s)(?=\s|$)
```

Означает оно очень простую вещь (пусть **N=10**):

1. `(?<=\s|^)` перед совпадением должен быть пробел или начало строки
2. Совпадением считаем любую из альтернатив:

   1. `\S{11,}` непробельная последовательность длиной от 11 символов **N+1**
   2. `\S.{0,9}` непробельный символ за которым следует до 9 любых символов **N-1**
3. `(?=\s|$)` после совпадения должен быть пробел или конец строки
4. `(?<!\s)` последний символ совпадения не может быть пробельным.

Comment: Я пишу программу на Visual Basic Excel. Он к сожалению не принимает такое выражение.

Comment: Вы заблуждаетесь. VB это язык семейства .NET. Вам просто нужно сделать `CreateObject "Application.Regex"` и получите всю мощь PCRE. Точно не помню CLASSID объекта. Уточните у гугля.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, тут как раз проще было бы обойтись без регулярных выражений. И быстрее будет.

```
function isWordCharacter(c){
    return c >= 'а' && c <= 'я'; // TODO
}

var s = "один два три большоеидлинное а б в г д е ж большое,пусть а б в";
var result = [], from = 0, prevSpace = 0, limit = 6;
for (var i = 0; i <= s.length; i++){
    var c = s[i];
    if (c == null || i - from >= limit){
        if (!isWordCharacter(c)){
          result.push(s.substring(from, i));
          from = c == ' ' ? i + 1 : i;
          prevSpace = -1;
        } else if (prevSpace != -1){
          result.push(s.substring(from, prevSpace));
          from = prevSpace + 1;
          prevSpace = -1;
        }
    }
    if (c == ' ') prevSpace = i;
}
```

Результат:

```
["один", "два", "три", "большоеидлинное", "а б в", "г д е", "ж", "большое", ",пусть", "а б в"]
```

Comment: Ваш алгоритм нерабочий. возьмите вот такую начальную строку `var s = "а б в г д е ж";`

Comment: А если "Один   два три  большое,но,пусть,большоеидлинное" то собьётся?

Comment: А, похоже, я неверно понял задачу. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Вы выбрали не тот язык, чтобы сравнивать регулярные выражения с "чистой" реализацией. В любом языке, который основан на байткоде, а регулярные выражения выполнены нативно (коим и является JavaScript, который Вы привели) - регулярные выражения будут значительно производительнее "чистой" реализации (и чтобы не вызывать дальнейших споров: даже компиляции V8 не спасают. В NodeJS регулярные выражения тоже выигрывают).

Comment: @ReinRaus, хм, а как же JIT?

Comment: Не спасает, к сожалению :( Да и взывать к JIT не совсем честно. Обычно в программах нет потребности постоянно применять регулярное выражение к тексту в цикле.

Comment: Ну, если нужно разместить строку в таблице, подозреваю, что строк будет очень много. Хотя да, конечно, это не то место, которое нужно оптимизировать.

Answer (score -1):

вот пример на python:
    s = 'Один два три большоеидлинное'
    print(s.split())

результат:
    ['Один', 'два', 'три', 'большоеидлинное']

Comment: При N=10 должно быть: "Один два", "три","большоеидлинное"

Comment: не совсем понятно что такое N

Comment: @АндрейКрузлик N - максимальное количество символов в одной из выходных подстрок.

Comment: @АндрейКрузлик То есть если 2 слова, даже разделенные пробелом, длиной меньше N, то эти 2 слова должны быть одной выходной строкой, а не двумя (даже учитывая то, что они разделены пробелом).

Comment: @smellyshovel Да. Если 2 слова, даже и разделенные пробелом меньше N, они должны быть одной строкой.

Comment: То что вы показываете - не алгоритм, а готовое решение на конкретном языке, причем не удовлетворяющее условиям вопроса.